# How to set up HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am interested in writing a java application using HtmlUnit, but I do not understand how to set up the dependencies listed here: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html

Is each entry on the page something you have to download?

Or I guess more specifically, could someone clarify for me what a dependency is and how you would add them to the IDE? I am currently using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just download the binary distribution of HtmlUnit. It contains all the dependecies. Then just add them to your project's build path.